# Запись в файл R: количество цифр после запятой

Tags: r, файловый-ввод-вывод, rstudio

Мне необходимо сократить количество цифр, выводимых после запятой, при записи в файл. То есть вместо 1.0043568853 меня устроит запись 1.00436.Не могу понять, как задать этот формат при выводе в файл в R. Для записи использую write.table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14260646/4827341

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!

Answer (score 0):

для форматирования таблицы можно, например, использовать функцию [`format()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/format), передав ей параметр `digits` с подходящим значением.

пример:

```r
write.table(data.frame(x=1.0043568853))
#> "x"
#> "1" 1.0043568853

write.table(format(data.frame(x=1.0043568853),digits=6))
#> "x"
#> "1" "1.00436"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>