# Считка файла в R

Tags: файлы, r

Здраствуйте! Мне нужно считать данные с файла полностью о всеми цифрами после комы, но почему результат не такой. Здесь код:

```
data<-read.table("D:\\...\\reglab1.txt", sep="\t", fill=TRUE, header = TRUE, numerals="no.loss")
data
```

Здесь сам файл(покажу 5 значений, их всего 200):

```
z                   x                   y

2.83677241557876    0.271010397933424   0.308330826694146
4.98716737258938    0.589598182588816   0.514913398073986
6.4123253407885     0.651744204340503   0.730453003430739
4.64199823203606    0.581982715521008   0.461400185944512
2.79394055883023    0.463688366813585   0.191102059325203
```

Результат у меня такой выходит:

```
               z          x           y
    1   2.836772 0.27101040 0.308330827
    2   4.987167 0.58959818 0.514913398
    3   6.412325 0.65174420 0.730453003
    4   4.641998 0.58198272 0.461400186
    5   2.793941 0.46368837 0.191102059
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Картинка - плохо. У меня например оно не грузится ибо ктото из админов трафик экономит и imgur режет.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, сделал

Comment: @Sheridan, например у первом столбце урезает 8 цифр после комы, во втором - 7, в третьем - 6

Comment: А это точно оно так считывает? Может оно выводит потом так?

Comment: картинку вы так в виде текста и не подставили. по поводу количества отображаемых цифр — это всего лишь формат отображения. см., например, этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266828/178576

Comment: @Sheridan соотвественно к коду, так считывает

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin предоставил у виде текста

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо за пример, но это запись у файл, меня интересует считка

Comment: по умолчанию считывается у вас и хранится всё число целиком. а вот отображается только указанное в настройках по умолчанию количество цифр.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это настройки R Studio?

Comment: r-studio — это [ide](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8). а программа, про которую речь в вашем вопросе, называется `r`. // вот вам наглядный пример — выполните и посмотрите на результат: `2.83677241557876 -> z; z; format(z, digits=15); format(z, digits=20)`